# How does the external js file work

Tags: javascript

Hope someone can explain it to me that how does the external js file work when we include them by script tags.

does it work just like the css file?

thank you

Comment: What you want to know? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I mean how the functions in the external js files are invoked or performed After we include them with script tags in HTML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that HTML is the document which a browser renders. There are various other resources that you can include

- Scripts (javascript & any such scripts supported by the browser)
- Stylesheet (css)
- images (referenced either in the script/css/inline elements)
- fonts

When the browser loads the document(HTML) (as part of your initial HTTP request), it tries to dereference the resources being referred to.
If there are references to any of the above resources, then the browser issues additional HTTP requests to get the resources.
If you are have javascript embedded in the HTML document, then the browser doesn't interpret it rather the javascript engine (part of the browser) interprets the script and runs it.

**Edit**
Also, please refer the answer provided by Marc B.

I suggest you to run the debugger in any of the modern browser to understand how the request for resources are made.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, now i start understand something.

Comment: You can also take alook at http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Answer (score 1):

given

```
file.js:

alert('foo');

file.html:

<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

is basically no different and works exactly the same as:

```
file2.html:

<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('foo');
</script>
```

except the first one involves another http request, which could potentially fail for whatever reason, leaving you with no JS code. On the other hand, embedding all your js code in every page is also a waste of bandwidth if you don't use all that code.

Comment: don't forget the caching

Comment: Thank you for your concrete example, simple but useful.